# $\frac{1}{2+\sin(x)}$: function is finite positive everywhere, but antiderivative is periodic. Where's the error?

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

While $\frac{1}{2+\sin(x)}$ is positive, finite, and well-defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, the antiderivative I found following in the footsteps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646068/integration-by-substitution-fail-for-int-frac11-sin-x-mathrm-dx), using one round of Weierstrass integration, and a second round of trigonometric integration, appears to be periodic:
$$\int \frac{1}{2+\sin(x)} dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$$

There clearly is an error -- somehow the $\arctan$ and $\tan$ should've canceled each other magically, but I can't quite put my finger on where the error is.

What is the rigorous way to do this, i.e. to obtain a non-periodic, monotonically increasing antiderivative?

Comment: What is the domain of the antiderivative?

Comment: @mfl This sounds like a trick question! I believe both the domains and co-domains of both the original function and the anti-derivative whould be $\mathbb{R}$, unless I'm missing something really obvious? :)

Comment: Actually $\tan x$ is not defined for $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Ahhh so the problem is I can't use Weierstrass integration there like it was used in the other Math StackExchange problem I've linked with $\frac{1}{1+sin(x)}$. OK, so that solves the problem with what I did wrong; but then what technique should I use instead of Weierstrass integration? Or should I still use it, but reassemble it piecewise manually at the end?

Comment: The issue is that with the Weierstrass sub you are using a discontinuous substitution on a continuous function. This is why the anti derivative has a periodic discontinuity. Not that there is anything wrong with that. The anti derivative can also be obtained through a bunch of trig identities (meaning no Weierstrass) but then again at some point, division by $cos^2x$ (from there the anti derivative becomes obvious) leads to the same discontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous, strictly increasing antiderivative of $1/(2+\sin x)$ is
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
+\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \bigg\lfloor \frac{x-\pi}{2\pi} \bigg\rfloor
+C.
$$
This is certainlly reassembling it piecewise manually, and doesn't suggest how one might come up with this expression (or an equivalent one) more directly.

Comment: Cool, thanks! And as @mfl pointed in the comment on my question, this is not defined for the corresponding values of $x$ where $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ is not defined, so those points also need to be taken care of manually